# Postgis 2.0 upgrade problem with postgres data?

Tags: postgis-1.5, postgis-2.0

I have a serious problem:
on Wednesday, April 2 OpenSUSE 12.1 is updated, and the package was to update the PostGIS-a version 1.5.3 to 2.0.0.
  After this operation, Postgres does not display records.
  In pgAdmin count the records, but seeing them in a table view, and by SELECT is a problem.
  I can not do dump:
pg_dump-h 127.0.0.1-p 5432-U postgres-Fc-b-v-f "/ home / admin / olddb.backup" Tomice

I get the message:
  pg_dump: SQL command failed
  pg_dump: Communication error with server :: ERROR: can not access the file "$ libdir/postgis-1.5 ': No such file or directory
  pg_dump: Your command: COPY public.armatura (gid, type, sub_typ, description, wys_g, wys_d, operator, the_geom) TO stdout;
  pg_dump: *** stopped because of an error

In view of the tables in PgAdminie my tables, I have a good number of records, but when you call the data is still the same.

I noticed that almost all functions have the following address:
  "$ libdir/postgis-1.5" that during the upgrade-u has been replaced by / PostGIS-2.0.
  I could perhaps remove the column geometry, but at the base of my ...

I attach screenshots of pgAdmin.
  Command did not help, sql for good-sounded names: postgis_upgrade_2.0.sql etc. ..
  Suddenly all the repositories of RPMs flown for PostGIS 1.5.3, and I can not go back to the old version ...
  At stake is 1 working day to 15 people. If anyone has any idea - I'll be bound.

I have no idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Revert your software to 1.5, then follow the HARD UPGRADE instructions in the manual, doing the dump step, then the software upgrade, then the restore steps. http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch02.html#hard_upgrade

Comment: Hi, its really great that in a few hours my problem was resolved. After revert the PostGIS to 1.5, I had all my data back. Your answer was really helpful. Thank you a lot.

Comment: The link moved to http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade

Answer (score 4):

I am a maintainer at Application:Geo.
I will restore postgis 1.5.3 binaries in the next few hours.

If you are in a hurry check 
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tzotsos:/postgis/openSUSE_12.1/
where the old binary is posted now.

Thanks for the report,
Angelos

Comment: All done ! Thank You for help, the repository was changed, I was revert the PostGIS to 1.5.3 and all my databases back!
I didn't expect that quick and professional response. 
I describe this case in the Polish forum QGIS.
Thanks a lot Angelos.

Comment: after the 15 reputations :-) only ...